# How to combine two search methods?

Tags: python, pandas

Please help, I have two ways to search, one time works, one time another. I would like to combine these methods to increase the number of items that could be found. What formula to do this? I assume you will need to add an additional column that will combine both search results.

[image]

Any help will be rewarding. Cells marked in yellow equal to Nan

[image]

Comment: if by search you mean is subset, you can do it by 'df[(conditionA) | (conditionB)]'. In this case should be 'df[df['Populacja'].isna() | df['Populacja2'].isna()]'

Answer (score 0):

this links will help you [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)
[isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html?highlight=isna#pandas.DataFrame.isna)